# "The method how..."

Tags: relative-pronouns, subordinate-clauses, relative-adverbs

> I know how he did it.
>   I know the way he did it
>   (NOT, I know the way how he did it.)

This is what we know. But one of my friends is insisting on using the following sentence :
**I know the method how he did it.**

I know it's incorrect. But I cannot explain it. Could you please clarify it?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds strange since its kind of mashing up two ways to say the same thing. Its OK to say

> I know how he did it

And also

> I know the method he used

But you can't put them together like that.

A "method" is something that is used, followed, etc. But a method isn't something you "do." And appending "how" after a noun is going to sound wrong in any context. "How" is typically used at the beginning of sentences or after verbs.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence
*I know the method how he did it.
might seem analogous to
"I know the person who did it."
In the latter sentence, the word "who" is a relative pronoun, with antecedent "person".
But the word "how" is not a relative pronoun. It has definitions as an adverb and as a conjunction:
[American Heritage Dictionary "how"](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=how)

You may note also that the meaning of "I know how he did it." is complete in itself.